# How do I cancel task waiting for a blocking call

Tags: c#, multithreading, uwp

I am a beginner in UWP application in c#. I need to cancel a task in when a blocking call is going on. Please refer to the code snippet below for better understanding.

```
TimeSpan timeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(10000);
CancellationToken token = new CancellationTokenSource(timeSpan).Token;

    await Task.Run(() =>
                   {
                     //This is a blocking call
                     Task.Delay(11002).Wait();
                   }, token);
```

As I know the if I do the blocking call like                          `Task.Delay(11002).Wait(token);` then the Delay task is canceled but my requirement is to cancel the parent task. Because I to do a sync socket write in the task.

Hope my problem is understandable to everyone.
Thanks

Comment: There is no 'parent task'.  You are creating a new task which is getting cancelled.  If you need to cancel a different task, then that task need the CancellationToken passed in, AND used for blocking calls.

Comment: token.Cancel();

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend creating the cancellation token source outside of the method you're going to use it and passing it in as Neil mentioned in his comment.

Here's an example showing how you can do this and how you can cancel it.

```
private async Task ParentAsync()
{
    TimeSpan timeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(10000);
    CancellationTokenSource cts = new CancellationTokenSource(timeSpan);

    await ExecuteAsync(cts);

    cts.Cancel(); // This will cause the execution to cancel.
}

private async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationTokenSource cts)
{
    await Task.Run(() =>
                {
                    //This is a blocking call
                    Task.Delay(11002).Wait();
                }, cts.Token);
}
```

If you're looking to cancel the execution of the parent method, you follow the same steps you've already done for the child method using the token to handle the cancellation of the Task.

Hope this helps!